Making btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver deterministic in Ammo.js
I read in a pdf by Shahin Rabbani that in order to make everything in Ammo.js deterministic, in particular I should “make sure the following flags in btSolverMode in btContactSolverInfo.h are cleared:
a. SOLVER_RANDMIZE_ORDER
b. SOLVER_USE_WARMSTARTING”
This is for bullet of course and I have not been able to make this work for Ammo.js I just don’t understand which functions I should use to set these parameters.
Also, if anyone has other tips on making Ammo.js deterministic I would be very happy. I want to make a deterministic version of 3d-dice/dice-box for a virtual table top. The problem is that I am very unfamiliar with Ammo.js.
I appreciate the help!

It seems like
const solverInfo = World.getSolverInfo();
solverInfo.m_solverMode &= ~Ammo.SOLVER_RANDMIZE_ORDER;
solverInfo.m_solverMode &= ~Ammo.SOLVER_USE_WARMSTARTING;

works.
